# How to use onSuccess with useQueries in react-query?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-query

```
import { useQueries } from "react-query";
import axios from "axios";

const fetchFriend = id => {
  return axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/friends/${id}`);
};

const useDynamicFriends = friendIds => {
  const queryResult = useQueries(
    friendIds.map(id => {
      return {
        queryKey: ["friends", id],
        queryFn: () => fetchFriend(parseInt(id)),
      }
    })
  );

  const isLoading = queryResult.some(result => result.isLoading)
  return {isLoading, queryResult};
}

export default useDynamicFriends;
```

I need to use an `onSuccess` method just like we can use in `useQuery`, that will run only after all api call is done.

Comment: can you elaborate why you need that? what should happen when all api calls are done? there's currently nothing built in so you probably need a useEffect

Answer (score 0):

You can use queryCache.subscribe to achive that

```
  queryCache.subscribe(() => {
   
    const allQueriesResolved = queryResult.every(result => !result.isLoading);
    if (allQueriesResolved) {
      // Run your desired logic here
    }
  });
```

and import

```
import { useQueries, queryCache } from "react-query";
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no default/in-built function that takes care of 'after completion' code.

But, you can use JS methods on the resultant list returned by the 'useQueries' hook.

```
const useQueryResults = useQueries(queryConfigs);

const queryResolutionStatus = useQueryResults.every(result => !result.isLoading);

if (queryResolutionStatus) {
    console.log("All queries completed");
    // Run your 'after completion' logic here

  }
```

Note: This code logic gets executed every time there is a change is the state of any of the query in a list of queries provided to 'usequeries' hook